# How to remove page number from deckjs framework (using Slidify)

Tags: r, slidify, deck.js

I have created slidify presentation using deckjs framework and used "> *" to make things appear sequentially (like PowerPoint bullet points).

However, I found that it shows the page number differently. When I click next to show the next bullet point, the page number increases. For example, if I have 3 slides in my presentation and one of the slides includes 3 bullet points, total number of slides shows 6 slides.

How can I remove the page number from the slides, or just show the number of slides?

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to do is to pass the "countNested" option to deck.js (http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/docs/#deck-status)

The option can be added this way, at the bottom of the html file (which replaces the same line that hasn't the option):

```
$.deck('.slide', {countNested: false});
```

I don't know how easy it is to customize the html code generated by slidify though.

**edit:** to remove slide numbers, you need to delete the 5 lines below "deck.status snippet" in the html file.